# Can stored function with 2 OUT parameters be displayed in two columns when used as a part of select query

Tags: sql, postgresql

My table(`value_table`) has three integer type columns `value1, value2 & value3` and I have  a stored function `min_and_max(value1 integer, value2 integer, value3 integer, out min_value integer, out max_value integer)`

When I use `SELECT * FROM min_and_max(1, 2, 3)` I get two columns which have values 1 and 3 respectively.

But when I use `SELECT value1, value2, value3, min_and_max(value1, value2, value3) FROM value_table`, I get only four columns with the last column having two values separated by comma, for example, `| 1 | 2 | 3 |(1,3)|`.
I want to display the data in five columns like `| 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 3 |`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A function with more than 1 `OUT` parameters returns an anonymous record.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-PARAMETERS) If you use that record in a `FROM` clause, like in your first example, then the columns of that record are listed. If you use the record in a select list, like in your second example, then you get a single column with all record values enclosed in parentheses.

Getting the result you are looking for requires a [`lateral join`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM) like so:

```
SELECT v.value1, v.value2, v.value3, mm.min_value, mm.max_value
FROM value_table v,
     min_and_max(v.value1, v.value2, v.value3) mm;
```

The `min_and_max()` function takes its parameters from the `value_table` to which it is joined, then outputs its values in the same row as the values from the table.

Note that for a function the lateral join is implicitly possible so you can omit the `LATERAL` keyword.

Comment: thanks....it works when I use   `SELECT v.value1, v.value2, v.value3, mm.min_value, mm.max_value
FROM value_table v,
     min_and_max(v.value1, v.value2, v.value3)  as mm;`